# Change text colour according to json attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Working on a diagram using this d3js library
[enter link description here](http://bl.ocks.org/bollwyvl/9239214) ,trying to change the text colour according to the value of a json attribute called "checked" (if checked is true the text becomes red) Am getting the data from this json file :

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "children": [],
          "id": 50,
          "name": "gfj",
          "checked": false

        }
      ],
      "id": 51,
      "name": "malek",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "children": [
            {
              "children": [],
              "id": 49,
              "name": "nice",
              "checked": true

            }
          ],
          "id": 48,
          "name": "amira",
          "checked": false
        }
      ],
      "id": 47,
      "name": "mahdi",
      "checked": true
    }
  ],
  "id": 0,
  "name": "First",
  "checked ": false
}
```

Here's the js file :

```
;(function(d3){
  "use strict";
  d3.fishbone = function(){
    /*
      A Fishbone diagram implemented in d3.
    */

    // private variables
    var _margin = 50,

      // the data...
      _nodes,
      _links;


    // d3 selections and related things used in tick function
    var _node,
      _link,
      _root,
      _arrowId = function(d){ return "arrow"; },

      // the children accessor
      _children = function(d){

        return d.children;

        },

        _class = function(d){

             console.log(d)
             return "link link-" + d.depth;

        },
      // the label accessor
      _label = function(d){return d.name;},



      // a custom tick accessor
      _perNodeTick = function(d){},


      // arbitrary "nice" values
      _linkScale = d3.scale.log()
        .domain([1, 5])
        .range([60, 30]),

      // the main workhorse of the layout engine
      _force = d3.layout.force()
        .gravity(0)
        .size([
          window.document.documentElement.clientWidth,
          window.document.documentElement.clientHeight
        ])
        .linkDistance(_linkDistance)
        .chargeDistance([10])
        .on("tick", _tick);

    var fb1 = function($){
      /*
        the d3.fishbone modifier, expecting to be called against an `svg:svg`
        or `svg:g` bound to the root node of a navigable tree, i.e.

          d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .datum({name: "foo", children: [{name: "bar"}]})
            .call(d3.fishbone());

        in addition to the properties created by `d3.layout.force`, this will
        add some or all of the following properties, none of which are
        guaranteed to be stable, useful, or sane:

        - depth       int
        - horizontal  bool
        - vertical    bool
        - root        bool
        - childIdx    int
        - maxChildIdx bool
        - totalLinks  [int]
        - linkCount   int
      */

      _links = [];
      _nodes = [];

      // populate the nodes and the links globals as a side effect
      _build_nodes($.datum());

      // set the nodes and the links of the force
      _force
        .nodes(_nodes)
        .links(_links);

      // create the links
      _link = $.selectAll(".link")
        .data(_links);

      _link.enter().append("line");

      _link
        .attr({
          "class": function(d){ return "link link-" + d.depth; },
          "marker-end": function(d){
            return d.arrow ? "url(#" + _arrowId(d) + ")" : null;
          }
        });

      _link.exit().remove();



      // establish the node selection
      _node = $.selectAll(".node").data(_nodes);


      // actually create nodes
      _node.enter().append("g")
        .attr({
          "class": function(d){ return "node" + (d.root ? " root" : ""); }
        })
        .append("text");

      _node.select("text")
        .attr({
          "class": function(d){ return "label-" + d.depth; },
          "text-anchor": function(d){
            return !d.depth ? "start" : d.horizontal ? "end" : "middle";
          },
          dy: function(d){
            return d.horizontal ? ".35em" : d.region === 1 ? "1em" : "-.2em";
          }
        })
        .text(_label);

      _node.exit().remove();

      // set up node events
      _node
        .call(_force.drag)
        .on("mousedown", function(){ d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

      // select this so we know its width in tick
      _root = $.select(".root").node();
    }; // fb1


    function _arrow($){
      // creates an svg:defs and marker with an arrow if needed...
      // really just an example, as they aren't very flexible
      var defs = $.selectAll("defs").data([1]);

      defs.enter().append("defs");

      // create the arrows
      defs.selectAll("marker#" + _arrowId())
        .data([1])
      .enter().append("marker")
        .attr({
          id: _arrowId(),
          viewBox: "0 -5 10 10",
          refX: 10,
          refY: 0,
          markerWidth: 10,
          markerHeight: 10,
          orient: "auto"
        })
      .append("path")
        .attr({d: "M0,-5L10,0L0,5"});
    }

    function _build_nodes(node){
      /*
        this builds up the real/fake nodes and links needed
        - a node on the "spine" can be like:
          - o--->

              |
          - o-+->

              |
          - o-+->
              |

        - a node off a "rib" or "subrib" can be like:

          - o--->

              \
          - o--->

      */
      _nodes.push(node);

      var cx = 0;

      var between = [node, node.connector],
        nodeLinks = [{
          source: node,
          target: node.connector,
          arrow: true,
          depth: node.depth || 0
        }],
        prev,
        childLinkCount;

      if(!node.parent){
        _nodes.push(prev = {tail: true});
        between = [prev, node];
        nodeLinks[0].source = prev;
        nodeLinks[0].target = node;
        node.horizontal = true;
        node.vertical = false;
        node.depth = 0;
        node.root = true;
        node.totalLinks = []
      }else{
        node.connector.maxChildIdx = 0;
        node.connector.totalLinks = [];
      }

      node.linkCount = 1;


        (_children(node) || []).forEach(function(child, idx){
           var list = document.getElementsByClassName("link link-" + child.depth);
            //const htmlElement = document.getElementsByClassName("link link-" + child.depth);
        child.parent = node;
        child.depth = (node.depth || 0) + 1;
        child.childIdx = idx;
        child.region = node.region ? node.region : (idx & 1 ? 1 : -1);
        child.horizontal = !node.horizontal;
        child.vertical = !node.vertical;
          if(node.root && prev && !prev.tail){
          _nodes.push(child.connector = {
            between: between,
            childIdx: prev.childIdx
          })
          prev = null;
        }else{
          _nodes.push(prev = child.connector = {between: between, childIdx: cx++});
        }

        nodeLinks.push({
          source: child,
          target: child.connector,
          depth: child.depth
        });

        // recurse capturing number of links created
        childLinkCount = _build_nodes(child);
        node.linkCount += childLinkCount;
        between[1].totalLinks.push(childLinkCount);
        if(child.checked == true){
            //$(".link link-" + child.depth).attr(

           //     "css", { backgroundColor: "red" }


            //);
            //for ( var index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
               // list[index].attr(

               // );
            //}


        }

      });




      between[1].maxChildIdx = cx;

      Array.prototype.unshift.apply(_links, nodeLinks);

      // the number of links created byt this node and its children...
      // TODO: use `linkCount` and/instead of `childIdx` for spacing
      return node.linkCount;
    }


    function _linePosition($){
      $.attr({
        x1: function(d){ return d.source.x; },
        y1: function(d){ return d.source.y; },
        x2: function(d){ return d.target.x; },
        y2: function(d){ return d.target.y; }
      })
    }


    function _nodePosition($){
      // uses an SVG `transform` to position nodes
      $.attr("transform", function(d){
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      })
    }


    function _linkDistance(d){
      // make longer links for nodes with more children, or of lower depth
      return (d.target.maxChildIdx + 1) * _linkScale(d.depth + 1);
    }


    function _tick(e){
      /*
        the primary layout mechanism: a fair amount of the work is done
        by links, but override a lot of it here.

        TODO: enable tweaks to these individual rules
      */

      // this is a "little bit"
      var k = 6 * e.alpha,
        // cache some variables
        size = _force.size(),
        width = size[0],
        height = size[1],
        // scratch variables for lengthy expressions
        a,
        b;

      _nodes.forEach(function(d){
        // handle the middle... could probably store the root width...
        if(d.root){ d.x = width - (_margin + _root.getBBox().width); }
        if(d.tail){ d.x = _margin; d.y = height / 2; }

        // put the first-generation items at the top and bottom
        if(d.depth === 1){
          d.y = d.region === -1 ? _margin : (height - _margin);
          d.x -= 10 * k;
        }

        // vertically-oriented tend towards the top and bottom of the page
        if(d.vertical){ d.y += k * d.region; }

        // everything tends to the left
        if(d.depth){ d.x -= k; }

        // position synthetic nodes at evently-spaced intervals...
        // TODO: do something based on the calculated size of each branch
        // since we don't have individual links anymore
        if(d.between){
          a = d.between[0];
          b = d.between[1];

          d.x = b.x - (1 + d.childIdx) * (b.x - a.x) / (b.maxChildIdx + 1);
          d.y = b.y - (1 + d.childIdx) * (b.y - a.y) / (b.maxChildIdx + 1);
        }

        _perNodeTick(d);
      });

      // actually apply all changes
      _node.call(_nodePosition);
      _link.call(_linePosition);
    }

    // the d3.fishbone() public API
    // read-only
    fb1.links = function(){ return _links; };
    fb1.nodes = function(){ return _nodes; };
    fb1.force = function(){ return _force; };

    // callable
    fb1.defaultArrow = _arrow;

    // d3-style chainable
    fb1.margin = function(_){
      // how big is the whitespace around the diagram?
      if(!arguments.length){ return _margin; }
      _margin = _;
      return my;
    };

    fb1.children = function(_){
      // how  will children be sought from each node?
      if(!arguments.length){ return _children; }
      _children = _;
      return my;
    };

    fb1.label = function(_){
      // how will a label be sought from each node?
      if(!arguments.length){ return _label; }
      _label = _;
      return my;
    };

    fb1.perNodeTick = function(_){
      // what custom rules should be done per node?
      if(!arguments.length){ return _perNodeTick; }
      _perNodeTick = _;
      return my;
    };

    return fb1;
  }; // d3.fishbone
}).call(this, d3);
```

What I've been trying to do , is parse the json tree "Children " using foreach , get the value of the checked attribute for every child and try to change the colour of the text accordingly . I've been able to read the value of checked for every child and call it this way :

```
 (_children(node) || []).forEach(function(child, idx){
           
            if(child.checked == true){
               


            }}
```

But I don't know how to change the colour of the text  The colours are set by default in the css file  :

```
.label-0{ font-size: 2em }
.label-1{ font-size: 1.5em; fill: #06405a; }
.label-2{ font-size: 1em; fill: #06405a; }
.label-3{ font-size: .9em; fill: #888; }
.label-4{ font-size: .8em; fill: #aaa; }
```

I want to be able to change the colour of the names of the children that has checked set to true to red , but I have no idea as how to do it , as far as I know I can't change the colours dynamically in the css file , so the whole work needs to be done inside the js file or the html file.
This is the diagram :

[image]

Here's the html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>d3 Fishbone diagram</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      @import url("style.css");
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.1/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="d3.fishbone.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
      // create the configurable selection modifier

      var fishbone = d3.fishbone();

      var urlObject = new URL(document.location.href);
      var params = urlObject.searchParams;

      // Output — 10
      var url = params.get("url");


      //
      // load the data

      d3.json("./data.json", function(data){
        // the most reliable way to get the screen size
        var size = (function(){
            return {width: this.clientWidth, height: this.clientHeight};
          }).bind(window.document.documentElement),

        svg = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
          // firefox needs a real size
          .attr(size())
          // set the data so the reusable chart can find it
          .datum(data)
          // set up the default arrowhead
          .call(fishbone.defaultArrow)
          // call the selection modifier
          .call(fishbone);

        // this is the actual `force`: just start it
        fishbone.force().start();

        // handle resizing the window
        d3.select(window).on("resize", function(){
          fishbone.force()
            .size([size().width, size().height])
            .start();
          svg.attr(size())
        });


      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been stuck for a while and would really appreciate some help , I feel lost and don't know how to get this done since I'm new to javascript and d3 , how do I do this and where is it in the js file or the html file ? Thank you in advance